# numpy 1.6.1 argsort() strange behaviour?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I've an array `data` which has shape `(N,6)`. I am sorting this array by the final column such that:

```
sortx = numpy.argsort( data[:,-1] )[::-1]
sortedData = data[ sortx, : ]
```

where the `[::-1]` is used to sort the column from high to low, instead of low to high, and the data is *float64*. I then save this sorted array to a `.npy` file as follows:

```
numpy.save( 'file.npy', sortedData )
```

However, when I load the array back in again and check the sorting of the data, it doesn't appear to be in order! It's only some of the rows, not all of them which is weird.

```
data_again = numpy.load( 'file.npy' )
order = numpy.argsort( data_again[:,-1] )[::-1]
r = numpy.arange( len(data_again) )
```

If you compare `r` and `order` with `numpy.sum( order == r)`, you see that this does not equal N. Around 2% are not in the same order!

Firstly, am I understanding the above code correctly? Secondly, can anyone reproduce this? I'm using Python 2.7.2, numpy 1.6.1 on Linux.

Update: This behaviour occurs even directly after the first sorting, and before the save. So it's to do with the sorting itself. There are duplicate values in the sorted column.

Comment: There is a lot you could do to isolate the problem; does it occur without the intermediate save as well, for instance?

Comment: What is the dtype of data? Are they perhaps strings which look like numbers? It would help us a lot if you post a slice of `data` which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hey. Thanks. It does occur without the save. The dtype is float64.

Comment: Are there NaN values in your `data[:,-1]`? You can check with `np.isnan(data[:, -1]).any()`.

Comment: @unutbu There are no NaNs in the data. And they are all finite too.

Comment: Are there values in the final column which are equal? Are the rows that appear to be out of order, rows that share the same value in the final column?

Comment: @unutbu - Yes,there are repeated values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce the symptoms if the final column has repeated values:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.random((8,2))
data[::2,-1] = data[1::2,-1]
print(data)
# [[ 0.5488135   0.54488318]
#  [ 0.60276338  0.54488318]
#  [ 0.4236548   0.891773  ]
#  [ 0.43758721  0.891773  ]
#  [ 0.96366276  0.52889492]
#  [ 0.79172504  0.52889492]
#  [ 0.56804456  0.0871293 ]
#  [ 0.07103606  0.0871293 ]]
sortx = np.argsort( data[:,-1] )[::-1]
sorted_data = data[ sortx, : ]

order = np.argsort( sorted_data[:,-1] )[::-1]
r = np.arange( len(sorted_data) )
print(order)
# [1 0 3 2 5 4 7 6]
print(r)
# [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
print(np.allclose(order, r))
# False
```

---

np.argsort uses quicksort by default. Quicksort is not stable, so the order of tied rows is not necessarily in the same order as the original data.

However, even if you were to use a stable sort such as `mergesort`, when you *reverse* the result of `np.argsort`, for rows that are tied, the *higher* index comes first.

Thus, when you call `np.argsort` a second time, you do not get `order` equal to `r`.

You could produce that order by sorting the final column and using `np.arange(len(data),0,-1)` as the tie-breaker:

```
sortx = np.lexsort((np.arange(len(data),0,-1), data[:,-1]))[::-1]
sorted_data = data[ sortx, : ]

order = np.lexsort((np.arange(len(data),0,-1), sorted_data[:,-1]))[::-1]
r = np.arange( len(sorted_data) )
print(order)
# [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
print(r)
# [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
print(np.allclose(order, r))
# True
```

Using `np.arange(len(data),0,-1)` places the higher index first (for tied rows), so that when you reveres the indices, the lower index is first.

Comment: I see! Thank you for spelling it out in plain language. Cheers.